# List issues python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am writing a broader algorithm then this, but I think this issue is the reason it is not working.

Here the troublesome snippet of code..

```
difcheck = []
count = 1
questionsneeded = 4
required_dif = ["Easy", "Hard", "Medium", "Easy"]
required_topics = ["Graphs", "Math", "Geometry", "Fun"]
availablelist = [("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy")]
z = 0
answerlist = []

while z < questionsneeded:
    difs = required_dif
    topics = required_topics
    for x in range(len(availablelist)):
        if availablelist[x][0] in required_topics and availablelist[x][1] in required_dif :
        difcheck.append(availablelist[x])
            try:
                required_dif.remove(availablelist[x][0])
                required_topics.remove(availablelist[x][1])
            except ValueError as exception:
                continue    
    availablelist.append(availablelist[0])          
    answerlist.append(len(difcheck))
    del availablelist[0]
    print("availablelist ")
    print(availablelist)
    print("difcheck ")
    print(difcheck) 
    z = z + 1 
    del availablelist[0]
    del difcheck[:]
```

The code looks through the tuples in availablelist and compares tuple element 0 with every element in required_dif and tuple element 1 with every element in required_topics.

If both are found in both lists, the tuple will be added to difcheck.

It then repeats this until z = questionsneeded, tuples in available list SHOULD be shuffled everytime.

The output I get is

```
availablelist 
[('Fun', 'aasd'), ('Geometry', 'Medium'), ('Math', 'Easy'), ('Graphs', 'Easy')]
difcheck 
[('Graphs', 'Easy'), ('Geometry', 'Medium'), ('Math', 'Easy')]
availablelist 
[('Math', 'Easy'), ('Graphs', 'Easy'), ('Geometry', 'Medium')]
difcheck 
[('Geometry', 'Medium'), ('Math', 'Easy'), ('Graphs', 'Easy')]
availablelist 
[('Geometry', 'Medium'), ('Graphs', 'Easy')]
difcheck 
[('Graphs', 'Easy'), ('Geometry', 'Medium')]
availablelist 
[('Graphs', 'Easy')]
difcheck 
[('Graphs', 'Easy')]
```

The output I want is

```
availablelist 
[("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy")]
difcheck 
[("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy")]
availablelist 
[("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy")]
difcheck 
[("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy")]
availablelist 
 [("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd")]
difcheck 
[("Geometry", "Medium"), ("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd")]
availablelist 
[("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium")]
difcheck 
[("Math", "Easy"), ("Graphs", "Easy"), ("Fun", "aasd"), ("Geometry", "Medium")]
```

In an instance where an element in required_topics or required_dif is not in a tuple in availablelist, it would not be added to difcheck. In this case, we have a perfect match so everything is added.

The problem is probably very obvious, but I've gone all hazy and cant see it.

Comment: use `print()` to display variables and see what's going on in program (step by step) or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: also, indentation is not correct for while loop shown here

Comment: you have wrong indexes when you removes elements - you try to remove `topic` from `required_dif` list, and `dif` from `required_topics` . Use `print()` with exception - you can have error and you will don't know why program doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Good point. Seeing errors now.. Thanks

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why don't you describe what you want your program to do instead of trying to have us debug a program that may not even do what you want.  There's probably a much clearer way to do what you want than what you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

This part looks backwards

```
required_dif.remove(availablelist[x][0])
required_topics.remove(availablelist[x][1])
```

I think it should be

```
required_dif.remove(availablelist[x][1])
required_topics.remove(availablelist[x][0])
```

Also, the reason your list keeps getting smaller is because you have one append and two deletes on each cycle through the list.

```
 availablelist.append(availablelist[0])  # Add 1 item          
 answerlist.append(len(difcheck))
 del availablelist[0]                    # Delete 1 item
 print("availablelist ")
 print(availablelist)
 print("difcheck ")
 print(difcheck) 
 z = z + 1 
 del availablelist[0]                    # Delete another item
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help

Comment: He specifically said 0 is for dif and 1 for topics, why do you think it should be swapped? NM, I see now.

Comment: Because looking at the values, they're referencing the wrong lists.